# "amount including" vs. "amount for" (for interest payments)

Tags: grammar

Consider this example:

> Total amount paid is $100 (principal $80 and interest $20).

Which one is better in business writing?

> Total amount paid is $100, **including** principal $80 and interest $20.
>
> Total amount paid **for** principal and interest is $100.

But I would like to say the details (how much is the principal and interest, not just total).

Comment: Your first example is correct. (The total comprises/includes the principal and the interest.) The total is NOT paid for the principal and interest; It IS the principal plus the interest.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to describe something made up of other things, and use a full sentence for it rather than a summary like you have in parentheses, you want to use things like ***comprised of/comprising*** or ***made up of***, terms that indicate things that are *parts* of other things.

> The total amount paid is $100, **made up of** $80 principal and $20 interest.
>   The total amount paid is $100, **comprising** ...
>   The total amount paid is $100, **comprised up** ...

Comment: (Presumably not needing to be addressed to the OP). As a general point, explanations for downvotes are helpful.